# Why did von Stauffenberg have to dispose of the items before getting into the flight?

Tags: plot-explanation, valkyrie

In the movie [Valkyrie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0985699) (2008) Colonel Claus von Stauffenberg (Cruise) and his adjutant are returning to the air field after bombing Hitler's  meeting. Adjutant Lieutenant Werner von Haeften throws the unused explosive and the cutter from the running vehicle, which catches the sight of the driver. Later on, this results in their apprehension for the bombing.

This mission was a very well-planned and designed one which was implemented by a number of high officials who would have been Hitler's inner circle. Even von Stauffenberg was one who was the most passionate and committed to this mission. Then, how could both of them do something which not only gave them away, but also gave away the fact that the SS was not staging a coup.

**Why was it so mandatory to let go of those items before they boarded the flight? It's not like they were searched before they started from that air field.**

[image]

Comment: You do realize this is based on actual events, right?

Comment: @BCdotWEB.. Yes Sir, I do realize that. In the below mentioned wikipedia page there is a detailed description of how Stauffenberg and his associate came back after the bombing, but I could not find the mention that their driver caught sight of this act of doing away with the unused explosives.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20_July_plot#Escape_from_the_Wolf.27s_Lair_and_flight_to_Berlin

Comment: So since this disposal actually happened and is shown in the movie I'm not sure what your question is. As to why it's shown in the movie, that's obvious. If the question is why did they do this in real life...then I'm not sure the question is actually Movie related. Perhaps HistorySE mighe be more appropriate.

Comment: I found multiple references to this occurrence in books about the attempt; search Google Books for "Stauffenberg car bomb" and similar search terms. Considering that it is noted in books about the attempt, it stands to reason it was noticed by witnesses. Expecting Wikipedia to be complete about this is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: They weren't searched before they started, but that was also *before someone detonated a bomb near their boss.*  The rules might very well be different on the way back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine they were dumping any evidence that might link them to the assassination attempt. They couldn't risk being searched and that would be a possibility after landing since they couldn't know what was transpiring with the situation on the ground while they were in the air.

The "sloppiness" with the disposal may have been nerves and adrenaline.